# Angular Moment dynamic timezone from user settings

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a mobile application using Ionic that allows a user to create log entries, and allows them to choose which timezone they're in. The chosen timezone is not always their current timezone they are in. I am using the [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library to do this.

Things are mostly working, but I need to have the `angularMomentConfig` be a dynamic value, based on the user's chosen settings. If I hardcode the timezone, everything works for that timezone.

```
.constant('angularMomentConfig', {
  timezone: 'America/Buenos_Aires'
})
```

However, I need to have the timezone be a dynamic value based on their chosen timezone. I understand that the constant can't be changed in the angular app, so it's not the right thing to use. It's just I don't know what to use, or if it's possible. I've tried using a `.value()` instead of `.constant()` but that doesn't work with angular-moment. From what I'm seeing, there's no way to inject an outside value into a constant, but maybe there's some other way to set it that I'm not aware of.

Currently I have a `.run` that gets their settings and stores them locally, which includes their timezone:

```
.run(function(config, localStorageService, $http){
    $http({
      url: config.apiUrl + 'hos/settings/'
    }).then(function(data) {
      localStorageService.set('settings', data.data);

      // their timezone is here
      console.log(localStorageService.get('settings').timezone);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides setting `angularMomentConfig` constant you can also use the **amMoment** service and invoke at anytime its `changeTimezone()` method like in this code:

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, amMoment) {

    amMoment.changeTimezone('America/Buenos_Aires');

});
```

So, for example, you can use this method inside your `.run()` function.

Here is a working snippet which exemplifies those method and `changeLocale` as well:

```js
angular.module('timeApp', ['angularMoment'])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, amMoment) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.time = new Date();

  $scope.timezones = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'America/Buenos_Aires',
    locale: 'pt'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Europe/Paris',
    locale: 'fr'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Australia/Melbourne',
    locale: 'en'
  }];

  $scope.updateTz = function() {
    console.log("$scope.timezone=", $scope.timezone)
    amMoment.changeTimezone($scope.timezone.name);
    amMoment.changeLocale($scope.timezone.locale);
  }

  // initial default values
  $scope.timezone = $scope.timezones[0];
  $scope.updateTz();

});
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="//momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/urish/angular-moment/master/angular-moment.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.2/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" ng-app="timeApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Time zones:</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="item as item.name+' ('+item.locale+')' for item in timezones track by item.id" ng-model="timezone" ng-change="updateTz()"></select>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <h2>Date Format <small>(filter)</small></h2>
    <time title="{{ main.time | amDateFormat: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a' }}">{{ main.time | amDateFormat: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a' }}</time>
  </div>
  
  <div class="well">
    <h2>Calendar Format <small>(filter)</small></h2>
    <time title="{{ main.time | amDateFormat: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a' }}">{{ main.time | amCalendar }}</time>
  </div>
  
</div>
```