# I need to display the datezone according to country in Angular

Tags: angular

Currently I am displaying the dateZone of IST and I need to display the datezone according to the users location.

app.component.html:

```
<td>{{scan.createdOn + 'Z' | date :'medium'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a localized date pipe for that.

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

Please check the i18n guide of the official Angular documentation here for more info: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-format-data-locale

Comment: Thanks for your time. In timezone what variable i need to display for all place.

Comment: You can check this answer for more help if you need to dynamically change the locale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067149/angular-moment-dynamic-timezone-from-user-settings